# How to define numbering for figures and tables?

Tags: tables, floats, numbering

I am writing a document with several figures with subsections numbers in the 2.1, 2.2, etc. format. I would like to number the figures in each subsection with a 3 digit format, for example: Figure 2.1.1, Figure 2.1.2, Figure 2.2.1, etc. How do I go about doing this? I am very new to latex.

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  we really need to know what document class you are using, since different classes make different assumptions about (sub)numbering. it would be best if you can provide a small example with several fully nested subsections and a couple of "figures" in each section.  just `\begin{figure}\caption{dummy caption}\end{figure}` should be enough; no actual graphics need to be included.

Comment: Change `section` to `subsection` in the answer to the duplicate question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code should do the trick; `chngcntr` is a small package that resets a counter (1st argument) each time another counter (2nd argument) is increased, and ensures the first counter is displayed as `2nd counter.1st counter`. If you want only to reset the first counter, and display this counter alone, use `\counterwithin*`.

```
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{figure}{subsection}
\counterwithin{table}{subsection}
```

Comment: I thought the name of the command is self-explanatory, but I can add some explanations…

Comment: Thank you, this worked. It doesn't work the same way for equations it seems, and I need to number those the same way. I'm using the article document class.

Comment: I've just tested, and I have no problem. What is your preamble?

Comment: Solved the equation problem with \numberwithin, didn't work in my main tex file but it did in the section tex file. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: You're welcome! Always glad to help.